# Dependency from .lib to another .lib

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, linker

I'm trying to build OpenCV v2.3.1 using Intel TBB and IPP. I used CMake to generate Visual Studio 2010 solution. Build is successful and I have opencv_core231d.lib among output.

Now I'm trying to link opencv_core231d.lib with my project. However, after specifying it in Linker -> Additional dependencies, I receive error LNK1104: cannot open file 'tbb_debug.lib'.

That's not the error about unresolved externals. Linker wants specific .lib file from me! How can that be?

I've done `dumpbin /all` of opencv_core231d.lib and for several sections it tells me:

```
Linker Directives
-----------------
...
/DEFAULTLIB:"tbb_debug.lib"
...
```

I tried to add tbb_debug.lib to /NODEFAULTLIB linker option of my project and it solved the problem. However, I just want TBB to be linked in opencv_core231d.lib.

The strange thing is I cannot find any reason why tbb_debug.lib is added to /DEFAULTLIB option of opencv_core231d.lib. I've searched all files in solution directory mentioning tbb_debug.lib as a substring, but the only matches was in generated .obj and .lib files - not in any source or project files. Where is the magic?

This question is not only related to OpenCV, but to whole process of working with .lib-files.

**Update**

There was a `#pragma comment(lib, "tbb_debug.lib")` directive in TBB include file _tbb_windef.h, so now I can understand from where did it go.

What I still don't understand is why it is not statically linked in opencv_core231d.lib? I've set Librarian -> Link Library Dependencies option to Yes. And there are no `#pragma comment(lib, "tbb_debug.lib")` directives in my project - I've checked preprocessor output.

Thanks.

Comment: My current theory why static linkage doesnt occur is because of tbb_debug.lib is only a stub-lib for corresponding tbb_debug.dll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's probably a `#pragma comment(lib, "tbb_debug")` somewhere in one of the header files you are including.

This is to do with using the thread building blocks by Intel. See this blog post for more information: http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2008/07/07/get-tbb-going-by-a-single-click/

Comment: You're right, thanks, but the questions are still present. See Update section in my post.

Comment: The link library dependencies option deals with project->project references rather than linker directives inherited from headers, as far as I'm aware. Look at the link command line for the lib - I'll guess tbb_debug isn't present. Include it manually and it will appear.